# Проблема с удалением примитива на холсте в tkinter по id и tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Написал небольшую игру, змейку, отрисовывающую по определенному правилу красные (или оранжевые, в случае с i == 1) квадраты-яблоки. Записываю возвращенные значения из **init** класса Apple в массив APPLES, состоящий строго из 1го или из 2ух элементов. Когда пытаюсь удалить какой-либо объект из этого массива, возникают проблемы для второго случая (когда элемент один, все работает без нареканий). Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Пробовал через tag и использовать две разные переменные, ничего не вышло. А когда добавил разные цвета заметил, что изначально оба квадрата оранжевого цвета, а затем после прохождения по ним змейкой и вызывания удаления, они становятся красными.

Класс Apple:

```
class Apple(object):
    def __init__(self, segsOfSegs, i):
        TAGS = ["APPLE1", "APPLE2"]
        COLORS = ["RED","ORANGE"]
        IsPlaceFree = False

        while not IsPlaceFree:
            posx = SEG_SIZE * (random.randint(1, (WIDTH - SEG_SIZE) / SEG_SIZE))
            posy = SEG_SIZE * (random.randint(1, (HEIGHT - SEG_SIZE) / SEG_SIZE))

            IsPlaceFree = True

            for i in range(0, len(segsOfSegs)):
                if not IsPlaceFree:
                    continue

                for seg in segsOfSegs[i]:
                    if not IsPlaceFree:
                        continue
                    x1,y1,x2,y2 = canv.coords(seg.instance)

                    #checking if coords are taken
                    if  (posx == x1 and
                         posy == y1 and
                         posx + SEG_SIZE == x2 and
                         posy + SEG_SIZE == y2):
                         IsPlaceFree = False
                self.instance = canv.create_rectangle(posx,
                                  posy,
                                  posx + SEG_SIZE,
                                  posy + SEG_SIZE,
                                  fill = COLORS[i], tag = TAGS[i])
```

Первый кусок кода, где вызывается функция:

```
for i in range(0, GM):
        APPLE.append(Apple(segsOfSegs, i))
```

Второй кусок кода с удалением объектов:

```
for i in range(0, GM):
        headCoords = canv.coords(s[i].segments[0].instance)

        x1, y1, x2, y2 = headCoords

        #falling over edge
        if x1 < 0 or x2 > WIDTH or y1 < 0 or y2 > HEIGHT:
            IN_GAME = False

            whoLose = i

        for j in range(0, GM):
            #eat apple
            #print( canv.coords(APPLE[j]))
            if (headCoords == canv.coords(APPLE[j].instance)):
                    s[i].add_segment()

                    canv.delete(APPLE[j].instance)
                    print(APPLE[j])
                    APPLE[j] = None
                    APPLE[j] = Apple(segsOfSegs,j)
```

Comment: Теги тут вообще не нужны, насколько я вижу. Выложите полный код куда-нибудь, я посмотрю

Comment: https://github.com/PAKETIKk/Python

Comment: Вот, залил на GitHub все, что есть, одним файлом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка вот в чем: при создании каждого объекта яблока вы создаете два квадратика разного цвета один над другим (красный, потом оранжевый), id первого записывается в `self.instance`, потом id второго его заменяет. При удалении яблока удаляется только последний из квадратиков (оранжевый), остается фантомный красный.

Исправленный класс `Apple`:

```
class Apple(object):
    def __init__(self, segsOfSegs, i):
        TAGS = ["APPLE1", "APPLE2"]
        COLORS = ["RED","ORANGE"]
        IsPlaceFree = False

        while not IsPlaceFree:
            posx = SEG_SIZE * (random.randint(1, (WIDTH - SEG_SIZE) / SEG_SIZE))
            posy = SEG_SIZE * (random.randint(1, (HEIGHT - SEG_SIZE) / SEG_SIZE))

            IsPlaceFree = True

            for seg in segsOfSegs[i]:
                x1,y1,x2,y2 = canv.coords(seg.instance)

                #checking if coords are taken
                if  (posx == x1 and
                        posy == y1 and
                        posx + SEG_SIZE == x2 and
                        posy + SEG_SIZE == y2):
                    IsPlaceFree = False
                    break

            if not IsPlaceFree:
                continue

            self.instance = canv.create_rectangle(posx,
                                posy,
                                posx + SEG_SIZE,
                                posy + SEG_SIZE,
                                fill = COLORS[i], tag = TAGS[i])
```

Кстати, при проверке попадания яблока на чей-то хвост можно проверять только координаты одного угла, т.к. размеры квадратов совпадают:

```
for seg in segsOfSegs[i]:
    x1, y1, *_ = canv.coords(seg.instance)

    #checking if coords are taken
    if posx == x1 and posy == y1:
        IsPlaceFree = False
        break
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Прямо спасли, а то уже третий день голову ломаю)